# jquery class追加の件

Tags: jquery

jqueryの質問です。
下記のhtmlを`<br>`が付く時だけclassを自動で追加したいのですがどうすれば良いでしょうか？
追加したいclassは、3つです。

```html
<ul id="menu">
<li><a href="menu01">りんご<br>アップルパイ</a></li>
<li><a href="menu02">ぶどう</a></li>
<li><a href="menu03">いちご<br>いちごショート</a></li>
<li><a href="menu04">パイナップル</a></li>
<li><a href="menu05">みかん</a></li>
</ul>
```

jqueryで下のように変更したい

```html
<ul id="menu">
<li class="aaa"><a href="menu01"><span class="bbb">りんご</span><br><span class="ccc">アップルパイ</span></a></li>
<li><a href="menu02">ぶどう</a></li>
<li class="aaa"><a href="menu03"><span class="bbb">いちご</span><br><span class="ccc">いちごショート</span></a></li>
<li><a href="menu04">パイナップル</a></li>
<li><a href="menu05">みかん</a></li>
</ul>
```

どうかご教授ください。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 実際のHTMLで変更前と変更後の表現はできますか？頂いた質問ではちょっと私はわからないです。。

Comment: @keitaro_so さん、生のテキストだと HTML になっていたのですが、Markdown では生の HTML がそのまま HTML と判断されるため、リストとしてレンダリングされていました。編集しコードブロックとして装飾したので、今なら実際の HTML としてご覧いただけるかと思います。

Comment: 質問文は「class追加」ですが、期待するHTMLを見る限りclassだけでなくspan要素も追加されることを期待しているように見受けられます。

Answer (score 1):

対象のHTMLを文字列として直接参照して、分析、HTMLを再構築するパターンです。

```
$(function()
{
    var reg = new RegExp("^(.*)<[bB][rR]>(.*)$");

    $("#menu>li").each(function(i, e)
    {
        var htmlStr = $(e).children("a").html();

        var result = reg.exec(htmlStr);

        if(result === null)
        {
            return;
        }

        var newHtml = '<span class="bbb">' + result[1] + '</span><br><span class="ccc">' + result[2] + "</span>";

        $(e).children("a").html(newHtml);
        $(e).children("a").addClass("aaa");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

jQueryのセレクタ−で処理するパターンです。

```
$(function()
{
    $("#menu>li:has(br)").each(function(){
        $(this).addClass( "aaa" );
        s = $(this).children('a').html().split("<br>");
        $(this).children('a').html('<span class=\"bbb\">' + s[0] + '</span><br><span class="ccc">' + s[1] +'</span>');
    });
});
```